# How does java IoC framework ensure thread safety?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, inversion-of-control, java-memory-model

Recently I have read [a great tutorial of Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html). It says JVM only guarantees
the visibility of *final* field if no synchronization used. Then it occurs to me that when we use some IoC frameworks, we usually use setter injection/field injection which are not protected by *final* semantics. For example,

```
class SomeController {
    private SomeService service;

    @Inject
    public void setService(SomeService s){
        this.service = s;
    }
}
```

If it is possible for some thread to read a stale value of `service` after the injection? Or should we mark `service` as a *volatile* field?

Comment: It will depend on the IoC framework you use...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if we talk about spring...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are reading a "tutorial" (that is a rather weird name for such a complicated topic) that is *really* old. Also, that document is targeted towards people that (usually) write compilers or work around the JVM itself; I still find it an excellent write-up.

You are correct that visibility is guaranteed under *special* conditions; but `final` is only one of them. There are at least 3 (and not limited to):

- Use a proper locked field
- Use static initializers
- Use a `volatile` field.

In the end, this is called "safe publishing" and it is all about how callers, given a reference to an instance of `SomeController`, will perceive its fields (`service`). Are they guaranteed to see a non-null `service`?

Spring guarantees that it will be a fully initialized instance, but not in the sense that you might think. There is a principle in the `JLS` called "happens-before". It is also called a happens-before "relationship", since it involves two parties. For example one that does a write (calls that `setService`) and one that does a read (uses that `service`). It is said that the relationship is guaranteed and fulfilled (reading part sees a non-null `service`) when both parties follow some rules. Those rules are very strictly written [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5). In simpler words: you are guaranteed to see a non-null `service` *only* when one of those rules are followed.  One of them is mentioned by you:

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

But notice that it is not the only one there.

So, if Spring,  for example,  does all the injections in a Thread, and only *after* that calls `Thread::start` on it's context, then there is a rule [in the JLS here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

that will guarantee that `service` is injected and correctly seen as non-null.

---

This probably needs a bit more explanation here, so here is an example:

```
// (1) init Spring context and do the needed injections

// (2) call Thread::start with this context

// (3) use context in a different thread now
```

There are three rules that we need to follow here from that JLS document:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

This means that (1) happens-before (2)

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

This means (2) happens-before (3).

> If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

This means (1) happens-before (3). And this is the one we care about and it's just one way Spring can achieve proper visibility.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the visibility guaranteed by `Thread::start`. But I'm wondering if that is always the case? Since the lazy initialization is another common used feature of spring...

Comment: @wangt0907 well if I read the documentation of `@Lazy`, I see something like this : _In that context, it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies..._ so I guess internally they handle this. You can think in perspective - what if you had to implement a "lazy factory" - how would you do it? Spring follows (most-probably) same rules